# Extracting raster pixels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster file with two bands and a vector shapefile. I used raster extraction by mask and created the desired area. Now I want to calculate the number of pixels for Band 1 and Band 2 of the new clipped mask file. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Zonal statistics`, set your polygon layer as well as your raster layer as input and at `Statistics to calculate` select `count`. Run the tool. In the attribute table of the resulting layer, you find the number you're looking for.